# Get directory path when running java jar

Tags: java, linux, filenotfoundexception

I have some file under my java project, when I want to access them I use:

```
XMLS/file_name.xml
XMLS // dir name
```

But when I export to `.jar` file and run the script I get `java.io.filenotfoundexception` with the path of the jar location

```
/etc/..../XMLS/file_name.xml
```

Can anyone know how to get the right file path in unix/Linux? how can I tell if this folder exsits in my jar? thanks!